# Change background image color on canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have created a canvas with specific background color (lets say red). Now i want to drawn an image . The image I have is a computer icon but having white background .When I draw the image on my canvas , the canvas background is red but the image background stays white and hence it doesnt look good.
Is there any way I can change the background color of image to red or acheive my desired behaviour?

Thanks

Hasan

Answer (score 0):

As you say `I have is a computer icon but having white background`, so Yes you can; there are a lot image processing tools available online to change background color to transparent which is required by you to avoid overlapping. [Here](http://www.online-image-editor.com/help/transparency)  is one of them.